Vector poisson equation in cylindrical coordinates. What's wrong?
I am trying to solve this equation:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 A}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial A}{\partial r} - \frac{A}{r^2} + \frac{\partial^2 A}{\partial z^2} = -g
$$
This is basically the radial (or angular) equation of the vector laplacian in cylindrical coordinates for a system with azimuthal symmetry, that is, $A = A(r, z)$. In summary, poisson equation.
Using a grid where $r\in [0, R]$ and $z\in[-L, L]$, with equal spacing $h$, I can discretize it:
$$
\frac{A_{i,j+1} + A_{i,j-1} - 2A_{i,j}}{h^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{A_{i,j+1} - A_{i,j-1}}{2h} - \frac{1}{r^2}A_{ij} + \frac{A_{i+1,j} + A_{i-1,j} - 2A_{i,j}}{h^2} = -g
$$
Multiplying everything by $h^2$:
$$
A_{i,j+1} + A_{i,j-1} - 2A_{i,j} + \frac{h}{2r}\left(A_{i,j+1} - A_{i,j-1}\right) - \frac{h^2}{r^2}A_{ij} + A_{i+1,j} + A_{i-1,j} - 2A_{i,j} = -h^2g
$$
Re-arranging:
$$
\left(-4-\frac{h^2}{r^2}\right)A_{i,j} + A_{i,j+1} + A_{i,j-1} + \frac{h}{2r}\left(A_{i,j+1} - A_{i,j-1}\right) + A_{i+1,j} + A_{i-1,j}= -h^2g
$$
Therefore:
$$
A_{ij} = \frac{1}{4 + \frac{h^2}{r^2}}\left[
A_{i,j+1} + A_{i,j-1} + A_{i+1,j} + A_{i-1,j} + \frac{h}{2r}\left(A_{i,j+1} - A_{i,j-1}\right) + h^2 g\right]
$$
I've been using jacobi iterations with neumann conditions with zero derivative at the boundary $z=-L$, $z=L$ and $r=R$. Furthermore, by symmetry, it can be argued that $A(r=0, z) = 0$, therefore, I've been imposing dirichlet boundary $A=0$ at $r=0$.
I have the analytical solution for a physical system that obeys this equation (the magnetic potential of a current ring of radius $a$). In this case, $g = \frac{I}{a^2}\delta(r-a)\delta(z)$.
$$A(r,z) = \frac{Ia}{4\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(x) dx}{\sqrt{r^2 + z^2 + a^2 - 2ra\cos(x)}}$$
I've been trying to validate it, but so far I am completely stuck. I've been trying to make this work for two days now, and nothing. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, and I am starting to doubt even if the discretization itself is correct.
If you wish, here are the codes I am using:

https://pastebin.com/pdNFQwD1
https://pastebin.com/HWCFuij3


Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks.

Is this numerical scheme correct?
Is there something wrong with the code? (if you are so kind take a look at it..). Also, both jacobi and seidel iterations seemed to be giving different results.. aaaa!


FYI, in the classic book by Landau Lifshitz ("Electrodynamics of Continuous Media"), the analytic closed form of $A_{\theta}$ is given by using the complete eliptic integrals. See problem 2 of section 29 (page 124).
